# return pointer to item in vector (from iterator)

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I want to have a function which iterates over a vector & picks and chooses an element which it then returns to the consumer in the form of a pointer, i.e. the pointer should point to the item in the vector. What I have so far is:

```
#include <vector>
class data_t {
    public:
    data_t(){mydat=99;}
    ~data_t(){}
    int get_dat(){return mydat;}
    private:
    int mydat;
};
void *myfunc(std::vector<data_t> foo);

int main(void) {
    std::vector<data_t> container;
    data_t tmp;
    data_t *res=nullptr;
    container.push_back(tmp);
    container.push_back(tmp);
    res = (data_t*)myfunc(container);
    res->get_dat();
}
void *myfunc(std::vector<data_t> foo) {
    for (auto itr = foo.begin(); itr != foo.end(); itr++) {
        if (itr->get_dat())
            return &*itr;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

but I'm not sure about the `return &*itr` - as it doesn't seem ight to first dereference the iterator and then return the pointer o it. Plus even though `itr` is local, it does point to a globally available vector element.
How do I do this better?

Comment: Though I would not recommend using the current design, it *could* work if `foo` was a reference. As it is `foo` is a copy so you are returning a pointer to the element in the *copy* of `container` which ceases to exist at the end of `myfunc`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do far better - currently the behaviour of your code is *undefined* since you pass `foo` *by value* and so a returned pointer will be invalidated as that value copy will go out of scope.

It would be *far* less idiosyncratic to pass the vector by (preferably) `const` reference, and either return a `size_t` (or, pedantically a `std::vector<data_t>::size_type`) type for the index of the element, or an *iterator* (your value of `itr`) to an element in the container.

There's nothing wrong with the `&*` notation when used appropriately. It crops up a fair bit when working with smart pointers and optional types.

Comment: Thanks, but what If I want to be able to directly access the element after to `myfunc()` as in `res->get_dat();` - I've also updated the code segment in my original post.

Comment: @cerr: Return an index of that element; subsequent access is O(1); no worse than a pointer dereference.

Comment: `return &*itr;` can be replaced with `auto& item = *itr; return &item;` if the `&*itr` offends your style.  What Bathsheba said about UB still applies... that needs to be fixed too.  But your question was just about the aesthetics of `&*itr`.

Answer (score 2):

This function signature screams "wrong" to me

```
void *myfunc(std::vector<data_t> foo);
```

You shouldn't be returning a `void *`, and you shouldn't be taking the vector by value.

```
using data_vec = std::vector<data_t>;
data_vec::iterator myfunc(data_vec & foo);
```

Now you don't have to cast in `main`, nor do you have to initialise with `nullptr`

```
int main(void) 
{
    data_vec container;

    container.emplace_back();
    container.emplace_back();

    auto res = myfunc(container);
    res->get_dat();
}
```